# Prove that for all natural numbers $k$, $k^5-k$ is a multiple of $10$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> Prove that for all natural numbers $k$, $k^5-k$ is a multiple of $10$.

I found several answers for this here, but none of which would have considered seperately the cases $\pmod{2}$ and $\pmod{5}.$

Since any integer $n \equiv 0,1 \pmod{2}$ we have that $k^5-k \equiv0 \pmod{2}$ thus divisible by $2$.

However, the case $k^5-k \equiv0 \pmod{5}$ seems to be a bit trickier. Any integer $n \equiv 0,1,2,3,4 \pmod{5}$, but is this of any help as it seemed to be in the case of $\pmod{2}$?

Comment: Verify that the congruence class of $k$ modulo 5 is always the same as the the congruence class of $k^5$ modulo 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the case $\mathrm{5}$ use Fermat's theorem.

Comment: $k^5 \equiv k \pmod{5} \Rightarrow k^5-k \equiv k-k \equiv 0 \pmod{5}$?

Comment: $k^{\phi(5)} = k^4 \equiv 1 (mod 5)$

Comment: Doesn't Fermat's theorem state that $a^p \equiv a \pmod{p}$?

Comment: This is equivalent statements =)